# Using quaternions in Flutter to rotate a picture

Tags: flutter, dart, rotation, quaternions

I have an accelerometer and gyroscope that I connect to my phone via Bluetooth. I am able to read and store the data that I receive and if I transform the data into eulers I can use the data to rotate a line in CustomPaint. 
But as it is with Eulers, there is the gimbal lock and I would like to use Quaternions to rotate a line or picture, but even though dart has the vector_math library I don't know how to use that to rotate a picture or box in flutter.

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a quaternion from the Euler angles, build a rotation matrix from the quaternion, and then use the matrix with a transform widget. Here's a complete example:

```
class RotateEuler extends StatelessWidget {
  const RotateEuler({
    required this.yaw,
    required this.pitch,
    required this.roll,
    required this.child,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double yaw;
  final double pitch;
  final double roll;
  final Widget child;

  Quaternion get quaternion => Quaternion.euler(yaw, pitch, roll);
  Matrix4 get rotationMatrix =>
      Matrix4.compose(Vector3.zero(), quaternion, Vector3.all(1));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Transform(
        transform: rotationMatrix,
        child: child,
      );
}
```